# OpenGL 3.x .obj loader with ADS Phong "veiny-looking" sphere

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, opengl-3, wavefront

I've been trying to make my own basic .obj (Wavefront) renderer using the OpenGL 3.x core profile. I'm using the OpenGL SuperBible 5th ed. and the Swiftless tutorials as reference material.

The geometry appears to load correctly, so now I'm trying to get an ADS Phong lighting model to work, but something is screwy, and I think it has something to do with either my OpenGL calls or else maybe the way I'm loading my normals, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. (It could be some other problem too I guess, since I'm not an expert in OpenGL).

When rendering a simple cube, it almost looks right, but there's a weird point of light on one side:

[picture of cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QWhD.jpg)

When rendering a sphere, the lighting shows up with "veins":

[picture of sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V0pE.jpg)

Something is obviously very wrong with my code. Here are the sections of code which I think might be relevant. I'll be happy to post more/all of the code if necessary... let me know if I should post more.

file: objFileRenderer.cpp

```
#include "objFileRenderer.hpp"

namespace def
{

objFileRenderer::objFileRenderer(const char* fileToRender, float objScale)
{
    windowWidth = 800;
    windowHeight = 600;
    settings.majorVersion = 3;
    settings.minorVersion = 1;
    app = NULL;
    shader = NULL;
    vaoID = NULL;
    vboID = NULL;
    iboID = NULL;
    vaoID = new unsigned int[1];
    vboID = new unsigned int[3];
    iboID = new unsigned int[2];
    rotSpeed = 50.0f;
    rot = 0.0f;

    initSFML();
    initOpenGL();

    std::string objFilename(fileToRender);
    std::vector< float > vertices;
    std::vector< unsigned short > indices;
    std::vector< float > normals;
    std::vector< unsigned short > normalIndices;

    loadObj(objFilename, vertices, indices, normals, normalIndices);


    std::vector< float > colorA;
    std::vector< float > colorD;
    std::vector< float > colorS;
    loadMtl(objFilename, colorA, colorD, colorS);


    float* vertexArray = NULL;
    int numVertices = 0;
    unsigned short* indexArray = NULL;
    int numFaces = 0;
    vertexArray = vertexVectorToVertexArray(vertices, numVertices);
    indexArray = indexVectorToIndexArray(indices, numFaces);

    float* colorArrayA = NULL;
    float* colorArrayD = NULL;
    float* colorArrayS = NULL;
    int numColoredObjects = 0;
    colorVectorsToColorArrays(colorA, colorD, colorS, colorArrayA, colorArrayD, colorArrayS, numColoredObjects);

    float* normalArray = NULL;
    unsigned short* normalIndicesArray = NULL;
    int numNormals = 0;
    int numNormalIndices = 0;
    normalVectorsToNormalArrays(normals, normalIndices, normalArray, normalIndicesArray, numNormals, numNormalIndices);

    setupScene();

    putArraysIntoVAO(vertexArray, numVertices, indexArray, numFaces, normalArray, numNormals, normalIndicesArray, numNormalIndices);

    mainLoop(numVertices, numFaces, colorArrayA, colorArrayD, colorArrayD, normalArray, objScale);

    delete [] vertexArray;
    delete [] indexArray;
    delete [] colorArrayA;
    delete [] colorArrayD;
    delete [] colorArrayS;
    delete [] normalArray;
    delete [] normalIndicesArray;
}

objFileRenderer::~objFileRenderer()
{
    shutdownSFML();
}

void objFileRenderer::loadObj(std::string& objFilename, std::vector< float >& vertices, std::vector< unsigned short >& indices, std::vector< float >& normals, std::vector< unsigned short >& normalIndices)
{
    std::ifstream objFile(objFilename.c_str());

    if (!objFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: unable to open .obj file: " << objFilename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string line;
    while (objFile.good())
    {
        getline(objFile, line);

        // vertices
        if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == ' ') // if line in .obj file contains vertices
        {
            std::vector< std::string > tmpStrVerts;
            std::string subline;
            subline = line.substr(2);

            boost::split(tmpStrVerts, subline, boost::is_any_of("\t "));

            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it;
            for (it = tmpStrVerts.begin(); it != tmpStrVerts.end(); it++)
            {
                float vertex;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << *it;
                ss >> vertex;
                vertices.push_back(vertex);
            }
        }

        // normals
        else if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == 'n')
        {
            std::vector< std::string > tmpStrNorms;
            std::string subline;
            subline = line.substr(3);

            boost::split(tmpStrNorms, subline, boost::is_any_of("\t "));

            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it;
            for (it = tmpStrNorms.begin(); it != tmpStrNorms.end(); it++)
            {
                float normal;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << *it;
                ss >> normal;
                normals.push_back(normal);
                //std::cout << normal << std::endl;
            }
        }

        // indices and normalIndices
        else if (line[0] == 'f' && line[1] == ' ') // else if line in .obj file contains indices
        {
            std::vector< std::string > tmpStrIndices;
            std::string subline;
            subline = line.substr(2);

            // indices
            boost::split(tmpStrIndices, subline, boost::is_any_of("\t "));

            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it;
            for (it = tmpStrIndices.begin(); it != tmpStrIndices.end(); it++)
            {
                unsigned short index;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << *it;
                ss >> index;
                indices.push_back(index);
            }

            // normalIndices
            boost::split(tmpStrIndices, subline, boost::is_any_of("/"));

            int count = 0;
            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it2;
            for (it2 = tmpStrIndices.begin(); it2 != tmpStrIndices.end(); it2++)
            {
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    unsigned short index;
                    std::stringstream ss;
                    ss << *it2;
                    ss >> index;
                    normalIndices.push_back(index);
                    count = 0;
                }
                count++;
            }


        }
    }
    objFile.close();

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::loadMtl(std::string& objFilename, std::vector< float >& colorA, std::vector< float >& colorD, std::vector< float >& colorS)
{
    int extpos = objFilename.find('.');
    std::string mtlFilename = objFilename.substr(0, extpos+1) + "mtl";

    std::ifstream mtlFile(mtlFilename.c_str());

    if (!mtlFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: unable to open .mtl file: " << mtlFilename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string line;
    while (mtlFile.good())
    {
        getline(mtlFile, line);

        if (line[0] == 'K' && line[1] == 'a')
        {
            std::vector< std::string > tmpStrColorA;
            std::string subline;
            subline = line.substr(3);

            boost::split(tmpStrColorA, subline, boost::is_any_of("\t "));

            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it;
            for (it = tmpStrColorA.begin(); it != tmpStrColorA.end(); it++)
            {
                float rgbValue;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << *it;
                ss >> rgbValue;
                colorA.push_back(rgbValue);
            }
        }

        if (line[0] == 'K' && line[1] == 'd')
        {
            std::vector< std::string > tmpStrColorD;
            std::string subline;
            subline = line.substr(3);

            boost::split(tmpStrColorD, subline, boost::is_any_of("\t "));

            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it;
            for (it = tmpStrColorD.begin(); it != tmpStrColorD.end(); it++)
            {
                float rgbValue;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << *it;
                ss >> rgbValue;
                colorD.push_back(rgbValue);
            }
        }

        if (line[0] == 'K' && line[1] == 's')
        {
            std::vector< std::string > tmpStrColorS;
            std::string subline;
            subline = line.substr(3);

            boost::split(tmpStrColorS, subline, boost::is_any_of("\t "));

            std::vector< std::string >::iterator it;
            for (it = tmpStrColorS.begin(); it != tmpStrColorS.end(); it++)
            {
                float rgbValue;
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << *it;
                ss >> rgbValue;
                colorS.push_back(rgbValue);
            }
        }

    }
    mtlFile.close();

    return;
}

float* objFileRenderer::vertexVectorToVertexArray(std::vector< float >& vertices, int& numVertices)
{
    numVertices = vertices.size() / 3;
    float* vertexArray = NULL;
    vertexArray = new float[vertices.size()];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        vertexArray[i] = vertices[i];
    }

    return vertexArray;
}

unsigned short* objFileRenderer::indexVectorToIndexArray(std::vector< unsigned short >& indices, int& numFaces)
{
    numFaces = indices.size() / 3;
    unsigned short* indexArray = NULL;
    indexArray = new unsigned short[indices.size()];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++)
    {
        indexArray[i] = indices[i]-1;
    }

    return indexArray;
}

void objFileRenderer::colorVectorsToColorArrays(std::vector< float >& colorA, std::vector< float >& colorD, std::vector< float >& colorS, float*& colorArrayA, float*& colorArrayD, float*& colorArrayS, int& numColoredObjects)
{
    numColoredObjects = colorA.size() / 3;

    colorArrayA = new float[numColoredObjects*3];
    colorArrayD = new float[numColoredObjects*3];
    colorArrayS = new float[numColoredObjects*3];

    for (int i = 0; i < numColoredObjects; i+=3)
    {
        colorArrayA[i] = colorA[i]; colorArrayA[i+1] = colorA[i+1]; colorArrayA[i+2] = colorA[i+2];
        colorArrayD[i] = colorD[i]; colorArrayD[i+1] = colorD[i+1]; colorArrayD[i+2] = colorD[i+2];
        colorArrayS[i] = colorS[i]; colorArrayS[i+1] = colorS[i+1]; colorArrayS[i+2] = colorS[i+2];
    }

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::normalVectorsToNormalArrays(std::vector< float >& normals, std::vector< unsigned short >& normalIndices, float*& normalArray, unsigned short*& normalIndicesArray, int& numNormals, int& numNormalIndices)
{
    numNormals = normals.size() / 3;
    numNormalIndices = normalIndices.size();

    normalArray = new float[numNormalIndices];
    normalIndicesArray = new unsigned short[numNormalIndices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numNormalIndices; i+=3)
    {
        normalIndicesArray[i] = normalIndices[i]-1;
        normalIndicesArray[i+1] = normalIndices[i+1]-1;
        normalIndicesArray[i+2] = normalIndices[i+2]-1;
    }

    // load normals in index order
    for (int i = 0; i < numNormalIndices; i+=3)
    {
        int index = normalIndicesArray[i];
        normalArray[i] = normals[index];
        normalArray[i+1] = normals[index+1];
        normalArray[i+2] = normals[index+2];
    }

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::putArraysIntoVAO(float* vertexArray, int& numVertices, unsigned short* indexArray, int& numFaces, float* normalArray, int& numNormals, unsigned short* normalIndicesArray, int& numNormalIndices)
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID[0]); // create our vertex array object
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]); // bind our vertex array object so we can use it

    glGenBuffers(2, &iboID[0]); // generate our index buffer object
    glGenBuffers(2, &vboID[0]); // generate our vertex buffer object

//  normalArray holds normals in index order, so I shouldn't use this
//  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID[1]); // bind our normal index buffer object
//  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (numNormalIndices) * sizeof(GLushort), normalIndicesArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // set the size and data of our IBO

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[1]); // bind our normal vertex buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (numNormalIndices) * sizeof(GLfloat), normalArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); // set up our vertex attributes pointer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboID[0]); // bind our index buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (numFaces*3) * sizeof(GLushort), indexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // set the size and data of our IBO

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]); // bind our vertex buffer object
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (numVertices*3) * sizeof(GLfloat), vertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // set the size and data of our VBO and set it to STATIC_DRAW
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); // set up our vertex attributes pointer
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::setupScene()
{
    app->setFramerateLimit(60); // max 60 FPS

    glClearColor(0.4f, 0.6f, 0.9f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    shader = new Shader("shader.vert", "shader.frag");
    projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(60.0f, (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::renderScene(int& numVertices, int& numFaces, float*& colorArrayA, float*& colorArrayD, float*& colorArrayS, float*& normalArray, float objScale)
{
    sf::Time elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
    clock.restart();

    if (rot > 360.0f)
        rot = 0.0f;
    rot += rotSpeed * elapsedTime.asSeconds();

    float lightPosition[3] = { -100.0, -100.0, 100.0 };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    viewMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -3.0f, -10.0f)); // move back by 5 units
    modelMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(objScale)); // change last arg to 0.5f to shrink model by half
    modelMatrix *= glm::rotate< float >(glm::mat4(1.0f), rot, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

    shader->bind();

    int projectionMatrixLocation    = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "projectionMatrix");
    int viewMatrixLocation          = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "viewMatrix");
    int modelMatrixLocation         = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "modelMatrix");
    int ambientLocation             = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "ambientColor");
    int diffuseLocation             = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "diffuseColor");
    int specularLocation            = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "specularColor");
    int lightPositionLocation       = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "lightPosition");
    int normalMatrixLocation        = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "normalMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &viewMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniform3fv(ambientLocation, 1, colorArrayA);
    glUniform3fv(diffuseLocation, 1, colorArrayD);
    glUniform3fv(specularLocation, 1, colorArrayS);
    glUniform3fv(lightPositionLocation, 1, lightPosition);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, normalArray);


    glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);

    glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numFaces*3, numFaces*3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    shader->unbind();

    app->display();

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::handleEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;

    while (app->pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            app->close();
        }

        if ((event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            app->close();
        }

        if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
        {
            glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
        }
    }

    return;
}

void objFileRenderer::mainLoop(int& numVertices, int& numFaces, float*& colorArrayA, float*& colorArrayD, float*& colorArrayS, float*& normalArray, float objScale)
{
    while (app->isOpen())
    {
        renderScene(numVertices, numFaces, colorArrayA, colorArrayD, colorArrayS, normalArray, objScale);
        handleEvents();
    }
}


}
```

file: shader.cpp

```
#include "shader.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

static char* textFileRead(const char *fileName) {
    char* text = NULL;

    if (fileName != NULL) {
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rt");

        if (file != NULL) {
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
            int count = ftell(file);
            rewind(file);

            if (count > 0) {
                text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count + 1));
                count = fread(text, sizeof(char), count, file);
                text[count] = '\0';
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return text;
}

Shader::Shader() {

}

Shader::Shader(const char *vsFile, const char *fsFile) {
    init(vsFile, fsFile);
}

void Shader::init(const char *vsFile, const char *fsFile) {
    shader_vp = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    shader_fp = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const char* vsText = NULL;
    const char* fsText = NULL;
    vsText = textFileRead(vsFile);
    fsText = textFileRead(fsFile);

    if (vsText == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Error: vertex shader file not found" << endl;
    }
    if (fsText == NULL) {
        cerr << "Error: fragment shader file not found." << endl;
    }
    if (vsText == NULL || fsText == NULL)
        return;

    glShaderSource(shader_vp, 1, &vsText, 0);
    glShaderSource(shader_fp, 1, &fsText, 0);

    glCompileShader(shader_vp);
    glCompileShader(shader_fp);

    shader_id = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_id, shader_fp);
    glAttachShader(shader_id, shader_vp);
    glLinkProgram(shader_id);

    glBindAttribLocation(shader_id, 0, "in_Position");
    //glBindAttribLocation(shader_id, 1, "in_Color");
    glBindAttribLocation(shader_id, 1, "in_Normal");
}

Shader::~Shader() {
    glDetachShader(shader_id, shader_fp);
    glDetachShader(shader_id, shader_vp);

    glDeleteShader(shader_fp);
    glDeleteShader(shader_vp);
    glDeleteProgram(shader_id);
}

unsigned int Shader::id() {
    return shader_id;
}

void Shader::bind() {
    glUseProgram(shader_id);
}

void Shader::unbind() {
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

file: shader.vert

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Normal;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

smooth out vec3 vVaryingNormal;
smooth out vec3 vVaryingLightDir;

void main()
{       
    // derive MVP and MV matrices
    mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
    mat4 modelViewMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

    // get surface normal in eye coordinates
    vVaryingNormal = normalMatrix * in_Normal;

    // get vertex position in eye coordinates
    vec4 vPosition4 = modelViewMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;

    // get vector to light source
    vVaryingLightDir = normalize(lightPosition - vPosition3);


    // Set the position of the current vertex 
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

}
```

file: shader.frag

```
#version 150 core

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform vec3 ambientColor;
uniform vec3 diffuseColor;
uniform vec3 specularColor;

smooth in vec3 vVaryingNormal;
smooth in vec3 vVaryingLightDir;

void main()
{
    // dot product gives us diffuse intensity
    float diff = max(0.0, dot(normalize(vVaryingNormal), normalize(vVaryingLightDir)));

    // multiply intensity by diffuse color, force alpha to 1.0
    out_Color = vec4(diff * diffuseColor, 1.0);

    // add in ambient light
    out_Color += vec4(ambientColor, 1.0);

    // specular light
    vec3 vReflection = normalize(reflect(-normalize(vVaryingLightDir), normalize(vVaryingNormal)));
    float spec = max(0.0, dot(normalize(vVaryingNormal), vReflection));

    if (diff != 0)
    {
        float fSpec = pow(spec, 128.0);
        // Set the output color of our current pixel
        out_Color.rgb += vec3(fSpec, fSpec, fSpec);
    }
}
```

I know it's a lot to look through, but I would be very happy to get some help with getting to the bottom of this problem, so thanks in advance to anyone who has some time to help me figure this out!

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but you have a memory leak.   You never delete vsText or psText in shader.cpp, although you use malloc to allocate memory for them.  Indeed, you should never need to use malloc at all.  In this case I would pass in a reference to a std::vector<char>, resize the vector to the size of the file, fill it and then use that instead of a raw char *.  You could also use a std::shared_ptr<char> to hold your char arrays and receive that from the function.  Anything but malloc!!! :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're treating the indices correctly. OBJ's are tricky to parse in opengl because they provide data using a useless multiple-index format. Essentially you have to break down all of the vertices and normals and rebuild the indices such that for every vertex it's position/normal/color/whatever all share the same index. It's not a trivial task to reorder them, but if you look online for "obj vertex buffer" I'm sure you'll find hundreds of references and posts about it.

Try reading this and see if it makes more sense:  http://aresio.blogspot.com/2009/07/wavefront-obj-files-vertex-buffer.html

Comment: I think you're right that I'm doing the normals / normal indices wrong. It looks like in normalVectorsToNormalArrays() I'm only adding one normal per face. What I think I should be doing (and correct me if I'm wrong), is I should be adding a normal for each vertex. I'll try to fix that tomorrow and see if I get better lighting results. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I'm now loading a normal for every vertex (is that right, or should it be 1 normal for each face?). But I'm loading the normals in their .obj file's index order, so this obviously still isn't working properly, because like you said, the normals and the vertices **must share the same index**... I'm having a hard time trying to visualize how to achieve this and the pseudo-code at the link you gave me isn't making a whole lot of sense to me (I've been reading it over and over), nor is google turning up anything useful. I'll keep trying things, but could you (or someone) give me more advise?

Comment: My first advice would just be to not reinvent the wheel and go download Assimp (http://assimp.sourceforge.net/), so you can get on with more interesting things :) . I don't have time for a full blown explanation, but if you want to do it yourself it boils down to: create a new vector of structs called "vertex" that contain position, normal, texcoord, etc. Then go through the obj file and every time you find a unique pair of position/normal/texcoord, copy the data into a new vertex so that it's all together (a STL map is useful for detecting duplicates). Then use this new vector to draw from.

Comment: (more), it's not even enough to have a normal for every vertex, sometimes after processing you'll have more vertices when you started with (a vertex that is reused with two normals will need to become two vertices with one normal each) . Hope that helps!

Comment: That is quite a good explanation actually, thank you!! I'll check out assimp first and if it does what I want, I'll probably just use that... otherwise, I think I could get further using your suggested implementation. Thanks again for all the help and advise!